# Partial Inversion of pixels in Pytorch transforms

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to randomly invert some of the pixels of an image, that's what I mean by "Partial Inversion". This is definitely feasible using two for loops but I am looking for a faster operation since this operation is to be applied to a lot of images in the dataset. I didn't find any operation in the **PIL** documentation. I am attaching a sample image for the reference, assume it has all channels (RGB). Any help would be appreciated.

[image: sample_image]

Comment: You don't show what you expect as a result? Pixels inverted at random? Just the top half? Just the left third?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, I was expecting the pixels inverted at random, not just top half or so. I accepted Nicolas's answer since I thought I could still work with the output he showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you consider solutions other than `PIL`? It's very easy to manipulate pixels with `numpy`. To invert, just subtract the array values from 255.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(x, _), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x = x[0]

x = torch.cat([x[:14, :], 255 - x[14:, :]])

plt.imshow(x.numpy(), cmap='Greys')
```

[image]

You can call it in your transforms like this:

```
torchvision.transforms.Lambda(lambda x: torch.cat([x[:14, :], 255 - x[14:, :]]))
```

Comment: Actually I am working in Pytorch environment where I will use transforms operation on each image in the dataset, PIL is the format most suited for applying transformations. I am not sure if I can plug the above answer back into PIL format.

Comment: torch transforms can be applied to pil images or tensors. i edited my answer for the latter